# golang sync.WaitGroup never completes

Tags: go

I have the below code that fetches a list of URL's and then conditionally downloads a file and saves it to the filesystem. The files are fetched concurrently and the main goroutine waits for all the files to be fetched. But, the program **never exits** (and there are no errors) after completing all the requests.

What I think is happening is that somehow the amount of go routines in the `WaitGroup` is either incremented by too many to begin with (via `Add`) or not decremented by enough (a `Done` call is not happening).

Is there something I am obviously doing wrong? How would I inspect how many go routines are presently in the `WaitGroup` so I can better debug what's happening?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    links := parseLinks()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for _, url := range links {
        if isExcelDocument(url) {
            wg.Add(1)
            go downloadFromURL(url, wg)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("Skipping: %v \n", url)
        }
    }
    wg.Wait()
}

func downloadFromURL(url string, wg sync.WaitGroup) error {
    tokens := strings.Split(url, "/")
    fileName := tokens[len(tokens)-1]
    fmt.Printf("Downloading %v to %v \n", url, fileName)

    content, err := os.Create("temp_docs/" + fileName)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error while creating %v because of %v", fileName, err)
        return err
    }

    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Could not fetch %v because %v", url, err)
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    _, err = io.Copy(content, resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error while saving %v from %v", fileName, url)
        return err
    }

    fmt.Printf("Download complete for %v \n", fileName)

    defer wg.Done()
    return nil
}

func isExcelDocument(url string) bool {
    return strings.HasSuffix(url, ".xlsx") || strings.HasSuffix(url, ".xls")
}

func parseLinks() []string {
    linksData, err := ioutil.ReadFile("links.txt")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Trouble reading file: %v", err)
    }

    links := strings.Split(string(linksData), ", ")

    return links
}
```

Comment: You're deferring `wg.Done()`, but you still have it at the end of the function. Try moving it to the beginning, before it has a chance to return from an error.

Comment: Pass a pointer to `wg` to the function rather than the struct itself.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There are two problems with this code. First, you have to pass a pointer to the WaitGroup to `downloadFromURL()`, otherwise the object will be copied and `Done()` will not be visible in `main()`.

See:

```
func main() {
    ...
    go downloadFromURL(url, &wg)
    ...
}
```

Second, `defer wg.Done()` should be one of the first statements in `downloadFromURL()`, otherwise if you return from the function before that statement, it won't get "registered" and won't get called.

```
func downloadFromURL(url string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) error {
    defer wg.Done()
    ...
}
```

Comment: Pointer boom. Solved my problem and learned something new. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

Arguments in Go are always passed by value. Use a pointer when an argument may be modified. Also, make sure that you always execute `wg.Done()`.For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    links := parseLinks()

    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)

    for _, url := range links {
        if isExcelDocument(url) {
            wg.Add(1)
            go downloadFromURL(url, wg)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("Skipping: %v \n", url)
        }
    }
    wg.Wait()
}

func downloadFromURL(url string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) error {
    defer wg.Done()
    tokens := strings.Split(url, "/")
    fileName := tokens[len(tokens)-1]
    fmt.Printf("Downloading %v to %v \n", url, fileName)

    content, err := os.Create("temp_docs/" + fileName)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error while creating %v because of %v", fileName, err)
        return err
    }

    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Could not fetch %v because %v", url, err)
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    _, err = io.Copy(content, resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error while saving %v from %v", fileName, url)
        return err
    }

    fmt.Printf("Download complete for %v \n", fileName)

    return nil
}

func isExcelDocument(url string) bool {
    return strings.HasSuffix(url, ".xlsx") || strings.HasSuffix(url, ".xls")
}

func parseLinks() []string {
    linksData, err := ioutil.ReadFile("links.txt")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Trouble reading file: %v", err)
    }

    links := strings.Split(string(linksData), ", ")

    return links
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Bartosz mentioned, you will need to pass a reference to your `WaitGroup` object. He did a great job discussing the importance of `defer ws.Done()`

I like `WaitGroup`'s simplicity. However, I do not like that we need to pass the reference to the goroutine because that would mean that the concurrency logic would be mixed with your business logic.

So I came up with this generic function to solve this problem for me:

```
// Parallelize parallelizes the function calls
func Parallelize(functions ...func()) {
    var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup
    waitGroup.Add(len(functions))

    defer waitGroup.Wait()

    for _, function := range functions {
        go func(copy func()) {
            defer waitGroup.Done()
            copy()
        }(function)
    }
}
```

So your example could be solved this way:

```
func main() {
    links := parseLinks()

    functions := []func(){}
    for _, url := range links {
        if isExcelDocument(url) {
            function := func(url string){
                return func() { downloadFromURL(url) }
            }(url)

            functions = append(functions, function)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("Skipping: %v \n", url)
        }
    }

    Parallelize(functions...)
}

func downloadFromURL(url string) {
    ...
}
```

If you would like to use it, you can find it here https://github.com/shomali11/util